# How can i get more than 230 'Reddit Thread' results with the 'RedditExtractoR' package?

Tags: web-scraping, sentiment-analysis

For a research paper me and my team want to analyze the effects of the Corona Pandemic on the overall sentiment on vaccines. We would like to analyse the Reddit threads that contain any information about vaccines. When i run my code it only gives me around 230 results. This is not only for 'vaccines' but also things as 'dog' or 'apple'. Does somebody know if it is because I need acces to the Reddit API or because something else?

I did try this code for scraping the threads about vaccines:

```
threads = find_thread_urls("vaccin", period='all')
View(threads)
```